# Asp.net Gridview CompareValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with multiple rows (records).

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLActionStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="LDSActionStatus" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ReportActionStatusID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ReportActionStatusID") %>' Enabled='<%# (int)Eval("ReportActionStatusID") == 1 %>' Width="100%" />

<asp:Button ID="BtnActionStatus" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save & Close" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?  Once set, this can not be changed.')" Width="100%" />

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CVActionStatus" runat="server" Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="1" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="DDLActionStatus" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Must set one of the Completion statuses" />
```

It works fine for one row, however if there are multiple rows it validates all rows together.

I understand it happens because the `ControlToValidate="DDLActionStatus"` repets for each row.

I tried to set the ID like `ID="DDLActionStatus<%# Eval('ReportActionStatusID') %>"` and the `ControlToValidate="DDLActionStatus<%# Eval('ReportActionStatusID') %>"`, but it doesn't work.

I know I could write a custom validation, but is there an easy solution that doesn't require a custom validation?

What I need is to each row be validate independent.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the `ControlToValidate` property. Add a `ValidationGroup` property to each control in a row with same value. But, make sure to keep it unique for all rows in your GridView. See following example.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLActionStatus" runat="server" ValidationGroup="MyGroup1" DataSourceID="LDSActionStatus" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ReportActionStatusID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ReportActionStatusID") %>' Enabled='<%# (int)Eval("ReportActionStatusID") == 1 %>' Width="100%" />

<asp:Button ID="BtnActionStatus" runat="server" ValidationGroup="MyGroup1" CommandName="Update" Text="Save & Close" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?  Once set, this can not be changed.')" Width="100%" />

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CVActionStatus" runat="server" ValidationGroup="MyGroup1" Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="1" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="DDLActionStatus" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Must set one of the Completion statuses" />
```

Make sure `ValidationGroup` is different for each row.

All the best!